# Жи, ши пишется везде?

Tags: орфография

Жи, Ши.
А в словах Желтый, Оранжевый пишется е, почему?

Comment: По Вашей логике, после Ж и Ш вообще не может быть других букв, кроме И)))))))

Comment: Такие вопросы бьют наповал... Они там что, вообще книг не читают? Надо же, до клавиатуры добрался уникальный @ivan(почему латиницей?), а правило в учебнике собственном прочесть духу не хватило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на орфографическую ошибку в формулировке темы вопроса: "пишетЬся". Надо бы исправить, некрасиво!
Теперь по сути вопроса. Возможно, я многих удивлю, но в некоторых официально утверждённых учебниках нач. школы правило так и формулируется: "ЖИ-ШИ не всегда пишется с буквой И", имея ввиду безударную Е (жЕтон). По-моему, таких авторов учебников надо лишать гражданства (как минимум!)

Comment: Кто его знает, кто здесь прав, кто виноват. Оправдывает, по-моему, то, что побудило задать этот вот вопрос, - дети воспринимают правило ЖИ-ШИ  как "после Ж и  Ш всегда пиши И", не заостряя внимания на выборе только между И и Ы. Вот они и заострили по-своему. Вероятно, до этих слов там есть и другое определение, мы ж его не видим.

Comment: Современные дети довольно часто применяют это правило  даже там, где нужно писать после Ж букву Е: жетон, желудок, желток. Они просто не знают, что после Ж и Ш пишутся и другие буквы. МНОГИЕ ДЕТИ НИЧЕГО НЕ ЧИТАЮТ!

Answer (score 3):

Мне вопрос напомнил вот этот перл:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что там нет выбора И-Ы. Это неизменяемый суффикс -ЕВ- в прилагательном. -ИВ- пишется только в словах милостивый и юродивый.
 А ЖЕЛТЕТЬ однокоренное с ЖЁЛТЫМ.

Answer (score 1):

В заданном вопросе, скорее, речь идет о словах "желтеть и оранжевый", в которых после Ж в безударной позиции произносится звук Ы.

Классическое, простое и понятное объяснение правила ЖИ-ШИ формулируется примерно так:

1) Правило ЖИ-ШИ без ограничений применяется для ударной позиции гласного: решить, жить, лживый, большие.

2) Безударный звук Ы надо проверить, так как звуки Ы и Э в безударной позиции произносятся одинаково (как Ы): живот - жить, широкий - ширь, оранжевый (безударный суффикс ЕВ), слышит (окончание ИТ 2-го спр.), свежим (каким?). Но: шелестеть - шелест, пишет (окончание ЕТ), в свежем (каком).

3) Если гласный нельзя проверить, его контролируют по словарю, правило ЖИ-ШИ не применяется: шинель, железо, жетон. Это орфограмма "Безударные гласные в корне слова".

Проблемы начинаются в том случае, если мы звук Ы в слове "жетон" начинаем обозначать буквой Е. Тогда не стоит удивляться, что школьники не понимают это правило.

Comment: Vera (Sharon), а как быть с такими словами, как лЫжи, мЫшь и т.д.?V